# Archivo temporal KYC Mango Pay

Tags: php, laravel

estoy intentando enviar un documento acreditativo de identidad para la api de Mangopay, y simplemente creo un input file en la vista y ejecuto el código en el controlador para enviarlo a la plataforma, pero me da este error: file_get_contents('image.png'): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

No se si debo crear un archivo temporal o algo parecido. No quiero almacenar el archivo solo enviarlo a la plataforma. Trabajo con Laravel.

```
  $UserId = Auth::User()->mangopay_id;
  $KycDocument = new \MangoPay\KycDocument();
  $KycDocument->Type = "IDENTITY_PROOF";
  $Result = $this->mangopay->Users->CreateKycDocument($UserId, $KycDocument);
  $KycDocumentId = $Result->Id;
  var_dump($request['document']);
 $filePath = base64_encode(file_get_contents($request['document']));


  $result2 = $this->mangopay->Users->CreateKycPageFromFile($UserId, $KycDocumentId,  $filePath);
```

Gracias

Comment: Que pasa si usas $request->file en vez de $request['document']?

Comment: Correcto funciono a la perfección, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estaba haciendo mal la petición, cambie `$request->file` por `$request['document']` y el problema se soluciono.